# To convert struct column names into rows in a parquet file

Tags: apache-spark, struct, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a sample json datafile as shown below:

```
{"data_id":"1234","risk_characteristics":{"indicators":{"alcohol":true,"house":true,"business":true,"familyname":true,"swimming_pool":true}}}
{"data_id":"6789","risk_characteristics":{"indicators":{"alcohol":true,"house":true,"business":false,"familyname":true}}}
{"data_id":"5678","risk_characteristics":{"indicators":{"alcohol":false}}}
```

I converted the json file to parquet and loaded into hive using below code

```
dataDF = spark.read.json("path/Datasmall.json")
dataDF.write.parquet("data.parquet")
parqFile = spark.read.parquet("data.parquet")
parqFile.write.saveAsTable("indicators_table", format='parquet', mode='append', path='/externalpath/indicators_table/')

from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)
fromHiveDF = hive_context.table("default.indicators_table")
fromHiveDF.show()

indicatorsDF = fromHiveDF.select('data_id', 'risk_characteristics.indicators')
indicatorsDF.printSchema()

root
 |-- data_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- indicators: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- alcohol: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- house: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- business: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- familyname: boolean (nullable = true)

indicatorsDF.show()
+-------+--------------------+
|data_id|          indicators|
+-------+--------------------+
|   1234|[true, true, true...|
|   6789|[true, false, tru...|
|   5678|         [false,,,,]|
+-------+--------------------+
```

Instead of retrieving the data as select data_id, indicators.alcohol, indicators.house etc,
I simply want to get a parquet data file with below 3 columns only . That is - the struct fields are converted to rows under indicators_type column name.

```
data_id      indicators_type     indicators_value
1234         alcohol             T
1234         house               T
1234         business            T
1234         familyname          T
1234         swimming_ppol       T
6789         alcohol             T
6789         house               F
6789         business            T
6789         familyname          F
5678         alcohol             F
```

May I ask how to do that. I am trying to accomplish this using pyspark. Also Is there a way to achieve this without hardcoding the literal details. In my actual data the struct data can extend beyond familyname and it could be even 100 of them.

Thanks a lot

Comment: post sample data ?

Comment: @Srinivas i have added the sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stack` to stack the columns:

```
df.show()
+-------+--------------------------+
|data_id|indicators                |
+-------+--------------------------+
|1234   |[true, true, false, true] |
|6789   |[true, false, true, false]|
+-------+--------------------------+

stack_expr = 'stack(' + str(len(df.select('indicators.*').columns)) + ', ' + ', '.join(["'%s', indicators.%s" % (col,col) for col in df.select('indicators.*').columns]) + ') as (indicators_type, indicators_value)'

df2 = df.selectExpr(
    'data_id',
    stack_expr
)

df2.show()
+-------+---------------+----------------+
|data_id|indicators_type|indicators_value|
+-------+---------------+----------------+
|   1234|        alcohol|            true|
|   1234|          house|            true|
|   1234|       business|           false|
|   1234|     familyname|            true|
|   6789|        alcohol|            true|
|   6789|          house|           false|
|   6789|       business|            true|
|   6789|     familyname|           false|
+-------+---------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without hardcoding the literal details. In my actual data the struct data can extend beyond familyname and it could be even 100 of them.

Comment: the solution works perfectly with the sample input data. However my underlying file is in parquet format(I converted the original json data into parquet format). When i apply the same code on underlying parquet data, i am getting the below error:


    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'stack(39, 'alcohol', `indicators`.`alcohol`, ....................]parquet\n"

Comment: i have updated the description with more details on input data

Comment: the solution works actually. i was getting the error due to a type mismatch in one of the struct elements. Instead of all the struct elements being boolean, one of them was int. Is there a way i can set indicators_value as string type as part of the stack command?

Comment: @sabra2121 I guess so, try to replace `indicators.%s` with `cast(indicators.%s as string)`

Comment: works perfectly.. Thanks a lot @mck ! posting the updated expression:

stack_expr = 'stack(' + str(len(indDF.select('indicators.*').columns)) + ', ' + ', '.join(["'%s', cast(indicators.%s as string)" % (col,col) for col in indDF.select('indicators.*').columns]) + ') as (indicators_type, indicators_value)'

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using explode:

```
val df = spark.sql(""" with t1( 
select 1234 data_id, named_struct('alcohol',true, 'house',false, 'business', true, 'familyname', false) as indicators
union
select 6789 data_id, named_struct('alcohol',true, 'house',false, 'business', true, 'familyname', false) as indicators
) 
select * from t1
""")

df.show(false)
df.printSchema

+-------+--------------------------+
|data_id|indicators                |
+-------+--------------------------+
|6789   |[true, false, true, false]|
|1234   |[true, false, true, false]|
+-------+--------------------------+

root
 |-- data_id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- indicators: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- alcohol: boolean (nullable = false)
 |    |-- house: boolean (nullable = false)
 |    |-- business: boolean (nullable = false)
 |    |-- familyname: boolean (nullable = false)


val df2 = df.withColumn("x", explode(array( 
          map(lit("alcohol") ,col("indicators.alcohol")),
          map(lit("house"), col("indicators.house")),
          map(lit("business"), col("indicators.business")),
          map(lit("familyname"), col("indicators.familyname"))
                          )))

df2.select(col("data_id"),map_keys(col("x"))(0), map_values(col("x"))(0)).show

+-------+--------------+----------------+
|data_id|map_keys(x)[0]|map_values(x)[0]|
+-------+--------------+----------------+
|   6789|       alcohol|            true|
|   6789|         house|           false|
|   6789|      business|            true|
|   6789|    familyname|           false|
|   1234|       alcohol|            true|
|   1234|         house|           false|
|   1234|      business|            true|
|   1234|    familyname|           false|
+-------+--------------+----------------+
```

Update-1:

To get the indicators struct columns dynamically, use the below approach.

```
val colsx = df.select("indicators.*").columns

colsx: Array[String] = Array(alcohol, house, business, familyname)

val exp1 = colsx.map( x => s""" map("${x}", indicators.${x})  """ ).mkString(",")

val exp2 = " explode(array( " + exp1 + " )) "

val df2 = df.withColumn("x",expr(exp2))

df2.select(col("data_id"),map_keys(col("x"))(0).as("indicator_key"), map_values(col("x"))(0).as("indicator_value")).show

+-------+-------------+---------------+
|data_id|indicator_key|indicator_value|
+-------+-------------+---------------+
|   6789|      alcohol|           true|
|   6789|        house|          false|
|   6789|     business|           true|
|   6789|   familyname|          false|
|   1234|      alcohol|           true|
|   1234|        house|          false|
|   1234|     business|           true|
|   1234|   familyname|          false|
+-------+-------------+---------------+
```

Comment: This helps, but is there a way to achieve this without hardcoding the literal details. In my actual data the struct data can extend beyond familyname and it could be even 100 of them. I will add this point also to the main section

Comment: can  you check the update1 in the answer.